# VBA - Add Cell Value to Total Sum if Checkbox is Checked

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I'm not sure if the heading is accurately describing what my query is, so I'll try my best to describe it here.

I have a sheet that keeps track of expenses and income and I have a macro that I use to insert check boxes into selected cells, link the checkbox to those cells and finally, apply a condition for a conditional format once the checkbox is checked and likewise if it is unchecked again.

Here is code that does that:

**Sub:**

```
Sub Insert_Checkbox_Link_Cell()

    Dim rngCel, myCells As Range
    Dim ChkBx As CheckBox
    Dim cBx As Long

    Set myCells = Selection

    myCells.NumberFormat = ";;;"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each rngCel In myCells

        With rngCel.MergeArea.Cells

            If .Resize(1, 1).Address = rngCel.Address Then

                Set ChkBx = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)

                With ChkBx

                    .Value = xlOff
                    .LinkedCell = rngCel.MergeArea.Cells.Address
                    .Text = ""
                    .Width = 18
                    .Top = rngCel.Top + rngCel.Height / 2 - ChkBx.Height / 2
                    .Left = rngCel.Left + rngCel.Width / 2 - ChkBx.Width / 2
                    .Select

                    'Function Call
                    Selection.OnAction = "Change_Cell_Colour"

                End With

            End If

        End With

    Next rngCel

    If (Range(ChkBx.LinkedCell) = "True") Then

        myCells.Interior.ColorIndex = 43

    Else

        myCells.Interior.ColorIndex = 48

    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Function:**

```
Function Change_Cell_Colour()

    Dim xChk As CheckBox
    Dim clickedCheckbox As String

    clickedCheckbox = Application.Caller

    Set xChk = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(clickedCheckbox)

    If xChk.Value = 1 Then

        ActiveSheet.Range(xChk.LinkedCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 43

    Else

        ActiveSheet.Range(xChk.LinkedCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 48

    End If

End Function
```

So how this works is, I select the range of cells I want to have the checkboxes in, then I run the macro and it inserts the checkboxes as stated above.

Now I am wanting to add a little more and I am not sure if it is possible.

In the image below, I have listed income and at the bottom is the total. So, as the money comes in, the checkbox is checked.

***What I would like to do is this:***

While the checkbox is *UNCHECKED*, I don't want the value in the cell to be added to the total count at the bottom.

When it is *CHECKED*, then the value in the cell should be added to the total count at the bottom.

**Image 1: No Check Boxes**

[image]

**Image 2: Check Boxes Added**

[image]

**Image 3: One Check Box Checked**

[image]

**Image 4: 2 Checkboxes Checked**

[image]

Comment: "Now I am wanting to add a little more and I am not sure if it is possible"  yes, yes it is.  There are numerous approaches to this task; what is your preferred path and what have you done in said direction?  If you're asking for tips (this probably isn't the correct forum), I would suggest using VBA to loop and sum up X (where x is your value) if the checkbox.value = true, then y = x + y, where y is your sum of x as you loop.

Comment: @Cyril Thank you for the comment. I was asking 1) If it is possible because I wasn't sure given my already created macro, if I could still add this function/feature to the cell 2) A little guidance from a more experienced user (as you say though, perhaps then not the correct form) and 3) Hoping that someone would provide me with a code snippet to get started. After reading Toms initial comment, I realized I wasn't thinking clearly because I already have a conditional check in the cell which I could just amend lol

Comment: Glad you found an answer; when i was typing my suggestion, I was torn to go the route of SUMIFS or Loop, and went with Loop (loop would be able to associate if you have free-floating controls, while SUMIFS is pretty straightforward).  Cheers and have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this using Conditional Formatting and `SUMIF` formula to achieve this

[image]

I've used the following conditional formatting rules (You will need to change this for your ranges)

[image]

The conditional formatting is applied to both the cell fill and also the font text colour (to make the `True`/`False` be 'invisible')

In cell `C6` (a merged range) I have the formula

```
=SUMIF($D$3:$D$5,TRUE,$C$3:$C$5)
```

Where cells in the `D` range contain the values of the linked cells for the checkboxes (i.e. `True`, `False`)and `C` range is the values you want to sum.

This is a much simpler approach then any VBA solution and personally, I'd remove the formatting of the cells from your vba above and just use the conditional formatting.

If you're looking for a `VBA` way to initiate this (except for the `SUMIF` formula) I've updated your below code to add the conditional formatting

```
Sub Insert_Checkbox_Link_Cell()
    Dim rngCel, myCells As Range
    Dim ChkBx As CheckBox
    Dim cBx As Long

    Set myCells = Selection
    myCells.NumberFormat = ";;;"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rngCel In myCells
        With rngCel.MergeArea.Cells
            If .Resize(1, 1).Address = rngCel.Address Then
                Set ChkBx = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
                With ChkBx
                    .Value = xlOff
                    .LinkedCell = rngCel.MergeArea.Cells.Address
                    .Text = ""
                    .Width = 18
                    .Top = rngCel.Top + rngCel.Height / 2 - ChkBx.Height / 2
                    .Left = rngCel.Left + rngCel.Width / 2 - ChkBx.Width / 2
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next rngCel

    With myCells
        ' Set default value
        .Value2 = False
        ' Add conditional formatting for False value
        With .FormatConditions
            .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & myCells.Cells(1).Address(False, True) & "=False"
        End With
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            With .Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 9868950
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
            With .Font
                .Color = -6908266
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
        ' Add conditional formatting for True value
        With .FormatConditions
            .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & myCells.Cells(1).Address(False, True) & "=True"
        End With
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            With .Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 52377
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
            With .Font
                .Color = -16724839
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Tom, thank you kindly :) As I replied to Cyril above, I wasn't thinking clearly and only realized how simple the solution was after you had provided me the answer lol. BUT, this is what I was looking to do so I thank you for help. :)

Comment: @EitelDagnin Have a look at my update as well - I've modified your code to create the conditional formatting as well and removed the call to the click event

Comment: Wow! Thank you Tom, I just quickly copied and tested it and it works like a charm! I see a ton of changes, so I will have a look at them over the weekend. Thank you very much for all the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can give a value (eg: 1 for checked and 0 for unchecked) to the cell where the checkbox is added in your color change function. keep the cell's font color the same as the cell's fill color so that the value will be invisible to naked eyes. then in the total sum section, you can use sumif function.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer LOKE2707 :)